# Как сохранить объект через ObjectOutputStream в файл, если у этого объекта есть List других объектов?

Tags: java, сериализация

Как сохранить в файл объект, имеющий ArrayList из других объектом и загрузить его? Я использую сериализацию, но объекты из ArrayList'a не хотят загружаться и работать.

Тут я сохраняю в файл:

```
void saveChunk(Chunk chunk) {
    String currentChunkName = SAVES_FOLDER + "\\" + name + "\\" + "chunk" + chunk.x0 + "_" + chunk.y0 + END_CHUNK_NAME;
    File f = new File(currentChunkName);
    if(!f.exists()) {
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Can't create data for chunk " + currentChunkName);
        }
    }
    try {
        File chunkData = new File(currentChunkName);
        DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(chunkData));
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(dout);
            out.writeObject(chunk);
            for(Tree tree : chunk.trees) {
                out.writeObject(tree);
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Can't create ObjectOutputStream " + currentChunkName);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Can't save chunk " + chunk.x0 + "_" + chunk.y0);
    }
}
```

И здесь загружаю:

```
Chunk loadChunk(int x0, int y0) {
    String currentChunkName = SAVES_FOLDER + "\\" + name + "\\" + "chunk" + x0 + "_" + y0 + END_CHUNK_NAME;
    try {
        File chunkData = new File(currentChunkName);
        if(!chunkData.exists()) {
            generateChunk(x0, y0);
        }
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(chunkData));
        try {
            ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(din);
            try {
                Chunk chunk = (Chunk) oin.readObject();
                return chunk;
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Can't find chunk " + x0 + "_" + y0);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Это класс Chunk, в нём ArrayList объектов Tree:

```
public class Chunk implements Serializable {

public static final byte CHUNK_SIZE = 12;
private int[] floors = new int[CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE];
public List<Tree> trees = new ArrayList<>();

int x0, y0, x1, y1;

public Chunk(int x0, int y0) {
    this.x0 = x0;
    this.y0 = y0;
    x1 = x0 + CHUNK_SIZE;
    y1 = y0 + CHUNK_SIZE;
}

public void addNewTree(int x, int y) {
    Tree tree = new Tree(x, y);
    addTree(tree);
}

public void addTree(Tree tree) {
    trees.add(tree);
}........ect
```

Оба класса (Chunk и Tree реализуют интерфейс Serializable)
Но когда я пытаюсь запустить, ничего не работает, только серый экран.
Если я убираю Serializable из класса Tree, то программа запускается, но частично: работают только чанки без объектов Tree в ArrayList, на месте же вторых просто пустое место и вылезают исключения:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.ixnomad.game.level.nature.trees.Tree; class invalid for deserialization
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$ExceptionInfo.newInvalidClassException(ObjectStreamClass.java:150)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkDeserialize(ObjectStreamClass.java:790)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1782)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:791)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1909)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
at org.ixnomad.game.level.Level.loadChunk(Level.java:44)
at org.ixnomad.game.level.InfiniteLevelRenderer.checkVisibleChunks(InfiniteLevelRenderer.java:70)
at org.ixnomad.game.level.InfiniteLevelRenderer.renderLevel(InfiniteLevelRenderer.java:55)
at org.ixnomad.MainComponent$SoftwareComponent.render(MainComponent.java:156)
at org.ixnomad.MainComponent$RunComponent.run(MainComponent.java:140)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то все слишком сложно. Попробуйте так :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Chunk implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7218355930049793756L;

    private static final byte CHUNK_SIZE = 12;
    //private final int[] floors = new int[CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE];
    private final List<Tree> trees;
    private final int x0;
    private final int y0;
    private final int x1;
    private final int y1;

    public Chunk(int x0, int y0) {
        this.trees = new ArrayList<>();
        this.x0 = x0;
        this.y0 = y0;
        x1 = x0 + CHUNK_SIZE;
        y1 = y0 + CHUNK_SIZE;
    }

    public void addNewTree(int x, int y) {
        Tree tree = new Tree(x, y);
        addTree(tree);
    }

    public void addTree(Tree tree) {
        trees.add(tree);
    }

    public void saveChunk() throws Exception {        
        try (final ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(createFileName())))) {
            outputStream.writeObject(this);
            outputStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Can't write object : " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public Chunk loadChunk(int x0, int y0) throws Exception {

        final File currentChunk = new File(createFileName());

        if (!currentChunk.exists()) generateChunk(x0, y0);

        try (final ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(currentChunk)))) {
            return (Chunk) is.readObject();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println("Can't read object : " + ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

    }

    private String createFileName (){
        return SAVES_FOLDER + "\\" + name + "\\" + "chunk" + x0 + "_" + y0 + END_CHUNK_NAME;;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Chunk{" + "trees=" + trees + ", x0=" + x0 + ", y0=" + y0 + ", x1=" + x1 + ", y1=" + y1 + '}';
    }

}
```